# WPF: Element Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I need to link librarybar item's name to sync in a seperate textbock to identify what am i dragging, etc.

Is there anyway that i can bind the content text from here:

```
<my:LibraryBar 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Name="libcont" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Background="{x:Null}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
            Width="850" 
            Height="250"

            >
            <my:LibraryBar.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" >
                        <Grid>
                        <Image Source="{Binding dev_img}" Height="144" Width="128" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding name}" /> 
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:LibraryBar.ItemTemplate>               
        </my:LibraryBar>
```

to my textbox here:

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="libcontvalue"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
```

my vb code:

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mvdata.accdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM devices", con)

        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        libcont.ItemsSource = sdr
```

Comment: what is LibraryBar? and what is value you want to bind it to text block

Comment: A surfacecontrol were u can drag images. I want to bind the value of <Label Content="{Binding name}" /> to the textblock. whenever i do IsMouseSelected because this control does not have SelectedItem Property.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind your `TextBlock.Text` to the libcont.SelectedItem?

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=libcont,Path=SelectedItem.name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: It does not have the property SelectedItem unlike the listbox controls. :( i had dis from my surfacelistbox <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=sdevbox}" Text="{Binding name}" /> but the surface library bar only have SelectedGroup.